# Pass a list of colors from Objective-C to React Native

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, colors

I am trying to get a list of all the colors in an image in Objective-C. Note, I am COMPLETELY new to Objective-C - I've done some Swift work in the past, but not really Objective-C.

I pulled a library that more or less is supposed to pull all colors as part of its code. I've modified it to look like this (callback at the end is from React Native, path argument is just a string of the path):

```
getColors:(NSString *)path options:(NSDictionary *)options callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback) {
UIImage  *originalImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path ];

    UIImage *image =
    [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[originalImage CGImage]
                        scale:0.5
                  orientation:(UIImageOrientationUp)];



    CGImageRef cgImage = [image CGImage];
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(cgImage);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(cgImage);

    // Allocate storage for the pixel data
    unsigned char *rawData = (unsigned char *)malloc(height * width * 4);

    // Create the color space
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    // Set some metrics
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;

    // Create context using the storage
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

    // Release the color space
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    // Draw the image into the storage
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), cgImage);

    // We are done with the context
    CGContextRelease(context);


    // determine the colours in the image
    NSMutableArray * colours = [NSMutableArray new];

    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    for (int n = 0; n<(width*height); n++){

      int index = (bytesPerRow * y) + x * bytesPerPixel;
      int red   = rawData[index];
      int green = rawData[index + 1];
      int blue  = rawData[index + 2];
      int alpha = rawData[index + 3];
      NSArray * a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",red],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",green],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",blue],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",alpha], nil];
      [colours addObject:a];

      y++;
      if (y==height){
        y=0;
        x++;
      }
    }
    free(rawData);

    callback(@[[NSNull null], colours]);
```

Now, this script is fairly simple it seems like - it should be iterating over each pixel and adding each color to an array, which is then returned to React Native via the callback.

However, the response to the call is always an empty array.

I'm not sure why that is. Could it be due to where the images are located (they're at AWS, on S3), or something in the algorithm? The code *looks* right to me, but it's entirely possible that I'm missing something just due to unfamiliarity with Objective-C

Comment: You get `width` and `height` from the empty `CGImageRef` object?

Comment: is the CGImageRef object empty? Isn't image populating it? As I said, my knowledge of Objective C syntax is pretty rudimentary. I may be misunderstanding something.

Comment: Ah you are right - i misread how it's being initialized.

Comment: The code looks "OK", but seems a bit more complicated than it needs to be. I know nothing about React Native and how it interops with C/Objective-C but it seems unusual to pass back an `NSArray` of `NSArray` of `NSString` objects.  I think if you want a list of unique colors then return a set (`NSSet`) instead of an array, but the array of stringified numbers still feels awkward to me.  Can you pass back a set of struct of rbg numbers instead?

Comment: Also is ARC enabled?

Comment: What is ARC? And sure, I can pass any data structure back with a Javascript analog (so objects, arrays, etc are all fine)

Comment: Automatic Reference Counting.  I would expect you would need to do MRC (manual reference counting) when doing interop.  But you will need to check.  You can collect the RGB struct in a set but return it as an array; that's a common pattern.

Comment: That's a bit misleading really.  Objective-C collection classes can only contain Objective-C objects so you will need to create an RGB object and in order for `NSSet` to detect dupes you will need to implement `-isEqual` and `-hash`, so it gets even more complicated...

Comment: Well I’m not going to look into that just now probably unless it’s likely to be the issue. This is a very common implementation - in fact, across something like 4 or 5 libraries, this exactly piece of code is more or less duplicated with only minor changes (so all the libraries are derivative...), so unless it’s causing the issue, I don’t see a reason to update it

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code in an empty project and it performs as expected using an image loaded from the assets library. Is it possible that the `UIImage  *originalImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path ];` call uses an invalid path. You can easily validate that by simply logging the value of the read image:

`UIImage * originalImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: path];
 NSLog(@"image read from file %@", originalImage);`

If the image was not read properly from the file, you will get an empty `colours` array as the width and height will be nil there will be nothing to loop over.

Also, to avoid modifying the array after your function has returned, it is generally a good practice to return a copy of mutable object or an immutable object (i.e. NSArray instead of NSMutableArray):

`callback(@[[NSNull null], [colours copy]]);`

Hope this helps

Comment: Yep, I bet that's the issue: [Unknown process name] CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the path is correct, but apparently the image read isn't

Answer (score 1):

The issue was ultimately that the image download method was returning null - not sure why.

So I took this:

```
UIImage  *originalImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path ];
```

I changed it to this:

```
NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: path]];
UIImage  *originalImage = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
```

And now my image downloads just fine and the rest of the script works great.

Comment: Ok, cool. Please note that the above call is executed synchronously and if you are doing it on the main thread it will block the UI (and/or if taken too long kill the app). It is maybe worthwhile considering performing the procedure in the background and dispatching the callback on the main thread.

Comment: How would I go about that?

Comment: There are many ways to do it and it is long topic. You could wrap it in block and dispatch it to background queue like the example here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671042/moving-a-function-to-a-background-thread-in-objective-c .